# Dual-boot Ubuntu 15.10 on a Toshiba Chromebook 2

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, chromebook, 15.10, chromeos

I'm looking to install Ubuntu on a Toshiba Chromebook 2 but I want a proper dual boot, not the version that installs with Crouton; specifically I want to boot to Ubuntu 15.10. I have looked online but I can't find any resources that work properly for 15.10. Can someone tell me how to solve the problem, or point me towards a relevant resource containing instructions?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the act of installing Ubuntu on a Chromebook is off-topic here. We will offer support post-install, but not for the use of Crouton or the like.

Comment: 15.10 was end of life on July 28, 2016. This according to: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix That [doesn't really seem relevant](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/16132/please-dont-flag-old-questions-as-eol) -- this question was asked when new 15.10 questions were on-topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I currently have Ubuntu Gnome 15.10 installed on my Toshiba Chromebook 2. The process is to:

1. Remove write protect on the system board.
2. Modify the BIOS.
3. Install Ubuntu in the normal way using a Live USB thumb drive.

See my [how-to guide on installing Ubuntu 15.10 on a CB2](http://wp.me/p6Pit2-2b)

I have a more updated guide to show a [full dual boot of Ubuntu and Chrome OS](http://www.fascinatingcaptain.com/howto/dual-boot-chrome-os-and-linux)